# Set JDBC cursor type with Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, db2, spring-jdbc

We have developed a Spring Boot Java application which access a DB2 database.
Now the system has been live for some time, we see the DB2 database crash every few weeks, which has caused us to review what cursor settings we have used.
This is where I have struggled - I just cant seem to find a way to influence the JDBC cursor types through Spring. And I worry that we may now need to rewrite the application with direct JDBC calls in order to be able to influence the cursor settings.
I am not a spring developer but have worked extensively with JDBC over the years which is why I have been asked to look at this.

Comment: What settings do you want to influence? How would you do this in JDBC code?

Comment: What do you mean "see the Db2 database crash"? Edit your question to specify clearly and fully what you mean. Surely the correct course of action is to have experts examine that so called "crash" and to get expert advice on the best course of action?

Comment: Hi There, We have been struggling to get clarity from the DBA as to the nature of the crashes, and so the cursor setting recommendation has been borne from a code review. An example of cursor setting can be as follows when defining the statement which is used by the result set: Statement stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");